# Perl (or Python) and Excel is there a way to determine font types used in multi-line text in a cell?

Tags: excel, perl, formatting, ole, strikethrough

I have data coming as an Excel files where some cells contain strings that contain previous version of data represented as strikethrough characters. I know how to use Perl and OLE to parse/manipulate Excel files but I only seen text formatting being accessible on cell-level. Is there a way to access formatting on character-by-character base? The goal is to locate and eliminate all the text that was formatted as strikethrough.

Comment: It looks like you can access individual characters and character ranges with Win32::OLE: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=888927

Answer (score 1):

This is a VBA solution, as I don't have Python installed on my machine. Hopefully it can show the way to access the formatting of individual characters.

With the following is `Range("A1")`:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sentence As Range
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set sentence = ws.Range("A1")

    With sentence
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To .Characters.Count
            If .Characters(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough Then
                Debug.Print "strikethrough at character " & i
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Gives the output:

```
strikethrough at character 17
strikethrough at character 18
strikethrough at character 19
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` to access individual cells as well as complex cells with multiple formats.  Complex cells will use **Rich Text** formatting, which you can access with the `$cell->get_rich_text()` method.  Here is an example looking for the **<strike>strikeout</strike>** format, both in individual cells, and as part of a multi-format cell, adapted from the synopsis of [perldoc Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~dougw/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.65/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm).

[image: lazy_dog.png]

**parse_lazy_dog.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $file = 'lazy_dog.xls';
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse($file);

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;

            print "Row, Col          = ($row, $col)\n";
            print "Value             = ", $cell->value(),       "\n";
            print "Unformatted Value = ", $cell->unformatted(), "\n";

            if ( my $rich = $cell->get_rich_text() ) {
                # Multiple formats inside one cell
                print "     STRIKEOUT ->   ";                
                my $pos = 0;
                for my $rich_elem (@$rich) {
                    my ($char_pos, $font) = @$rich_elem;
                    if ($font->{Strikeout}) {
                        while ($pos++ < $char_pos) {
                            print " ";
                        }
                    } else {
                        while ($pos++ <= $char_pos) {
                            print "^";
                        }
                    }
                }
                print "\n";

            } else {
                # Entire cell has same format
                my $format = $cell->get_format();
                my $is_strikeout = $format->{Font}->{Strikeout};
                if ($is_strikeout) {
                    print "     STRIKEOUT ->   ";
                    print "^"x(length($cell->unformatted()));
                    print "\n";
                }
                print "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Row, Col          = (0, 0)
Value             = The
Unformatted Value = The

Row, Col          = (0, 1)
Value             = quick
Unformatted Value = quick

Row, Col          = (0, 2)
Value             = brown
Unformatted Value = brown

Row, Col          = (0, 3)
Value             = fox
Unformatted Value = fox

Row, Col          = (0, 4)
Value             = jumped
Unformatted Value = jumped

Row, Col          = (0, 5)
Value             = under
Unformatted Value = under
     STRIKEOUT ->   ^^^^^

Row, Col          = (0, 6)
Value             = over
Unformatted Value = over

Row, Col          = (0, 7)
Value             = the
Unformatted Value = the

Row, Col          = (0, 8)
Value             = lazy
Unformatted Value = lazy

Row, Col          = (0, 9)
Value             = dog.
Unformatted Value = dog.

Row, Col          = (1, 0)
Value             = THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPED UNDER OVER THE LAZY DOG.
Unformatted Value = THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPED UNDER OVER THE LAZY DOG.
     STRIKEOUT ->                              ^^^^^
```